# When I start up a remote thread in an application, why does it always crash when it tries to access data in the thread structure?

Tags: osx, thread, lldb, injection

I'm  on *OS X 10.10 64 bit (x86_64)* and created a chunk of memory called code with `vm_allocate`.  I allocate a chunk of memory for a stack.  I load a library to memory and determine an entry point to the library.  I write the library to my code buffer using `vm_write`, no problems there.

I setup the registers and call `thread_create_running` and run remote thread into another process.

Over in the other process the thread starts.  I'm using *lldb* and have it setup so when my thread starts it *breaks on that entry point*  I see my code.  I step through the code.

However it crashes when it tries to do the `_pthread_set_self`.  If I step into `pthread_set_self`, it crashes in 
`_pthread_mutex_lock` at the following instruction:

```
movq %gs:0x0, %rax
```

(Note: `gs` is `0x00000000` prior to the instruction where the crash occurs)

It's my understanding this instruction is an operation to retrieve the first segment of `gs` from a thread segment structure and move it into the `rax` register.

**My question is what do I need to do to prevent the crash that ensues upon execution of this instruction?**  Upon execution of this instruction I see `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in `pthread_mutex_lock`.

I tried putting in the code to `pthread_mutex_init`, followed by `pthread_mutex_lock` then `pthread_set_self`.  However when it hits the first `pthread_mutex_lock`, i get the same issue.  It dies at the same spot.

Any ideas?

My target app to which i don't have source code, is multi-threaded.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem.